# Send email to queue members using apex

Tags: apex, trigger, queue

I need to send email to queue members of queue on update case record based on some conditions.
There are multiple queues and on case there is one field based on that I need to send email...
How can I achieve this using trigger ....
Please suggest

Comment: can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: There is one lookup field(Euipment__c) on case .Whenever i change the X2nd_Level_Support_Needed__c field on Case  to 'Yes' then it will take the euipment lookup Object field (Fleet Owner_c) and it will look to the same custom setting with field value Fleet_owner_c .if its find then again there is one field on custom setting which is queue name , I need to send emai to that queue members/Queue Email .

Comment: so what is not working here.

Comment: i am not getting how to get queue members and send mail

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple approaches here:

- Send one `SingleEmailMessage` to each `User`. This is a great option if you can use it, because it does not consume your daily email limit.
- Collect the `Email` for each `User` and then call `setToAddresses` with that collection.

Either way, you can use this `SOQL`:

```
SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName = 'My_Group'
)
```

I also recommend implementing the `Lazy Load` pattern here (in addition to using a trigger handler, which you should research on your own to decide what's best for you).

```
public with sharing class MyClass
{
    public List<User> queueMembers
    {
        get
        {
            if (queueMembers == null)
                queueMembers = [/*query*/];
            return queueMembers;
        }
        private set;
    }

    // OR

    public List<String> queueEmails
    {
        get
        {
            if (queueEmails == null)
            {
                Set<String> uniqueEmails = new Set<String>();
                for (User user : [/*query*/]) uniqueEmails.add(user.Email);
                queueEmails = new List<String>(uniqueEmails);
            }
            return queueEmails;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

so in that case you can do something like

```
SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName IN: mapQNameWithIds.keyset();
)
```

**Note** Thanks @Adrian Larson for the query

and fill `Map<string, List<string>> emailMap = new Map<string, List<string>> emailMap()`
ANd then continue in your loop

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(Default_Case_Queue__c casedefaultSetting : Default_Case_Queue__c.getAll().values())  {
     if(casedefaultSetting.Fleet_PLC__c.equals(equip.Fleet_Owner_PLC__c) && mapQNameWithIds.containsKey(casedefaultSetting.queueName) ){
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
           sendTo.addAll(emailMap.get(casedefaultSetting.queueName));
           // Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the                      mail object.
           mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);


            // Specify the subject line for your email address.
            mail.setSubject('New Case Updated : ' + case.Id);

            // Set to True if you want to BCC yourself on the email.
            mail.setBccSender(false);


          // Specify the text content of the email.
          mail.setPlainTextBody('Your Case: ' + case.Id +' has been updated.');

           mail.setHtmlBody('Your case:<b> ' + case.Id +' </b>has been updated.<p>'+
     'To view your case <a      href=https://***yourInstance***.salesforce.com/'+case.Id+'>click here.</a>');
                   emailList .add(mail );

                    }
                } 
// Send the email you have created.
Messaging.sendEmail(emailList ); //keep this line out of for loop
```

Comment: How to fill this map {Map<string, List<string>> emailMap = new Map<string, List<string>>();
for(User u:[SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName IN: mapQNameWithIds.keyset()) ])
{
    emailMap.put(u.email, u);
}}

Comment: wht i need to put in map ?

Comment: In this map one side keep queue name and another side list of id

Comment: Did you just copy that soql straight from my answer? :P

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes with few changes :). Hope you will pardon me.